# Limit Rate of Print statements in Loop

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am looking for an efficient way to limit the rate of execution of print statements in a while loop.  I have a while loop with numerous logging statements that are executed depending on what the system is doing at that point (to log error messages etc).  I am trying to limit the execution of each log statement so that if an error is detected it does not log the warning every time it loops.  I do not want to only log the error once, the system must log the error at a set interval until the error is no longer detected.

An example of what I currently have is this:

```
while True:
  if True:                                  #Detect Error 1
    print("Print Every Second")             #Log error 1
  if True:                                  #Detect Error 2
    print("Print Every 10 Seconds")         #Log error 2
```

If the error check validates True, this logs the error every time the loop runs.  I want to be able to limit the rate of execution of the Logging statements.

I was able to create a proof of concept using the following code:

```
import time

def RateLimited(interval):
    def wrapper(func):
        wrapper.lastTimeCalled = [0.0]
        def rateLimitedFunction(*args,**kargs):
            rateLimitedFunction.elapsed = time.time() - wrapper.lastTimeCalled[0]
            rateLimitedFunction.leftToWait = wrapper.minInterval - rateLimitedFunction.elapsed
            if rateLimitedFunction.leftToWait>0:
                pass
            else:
              wrapper.lastTimeCalled[0] = time.time()
              return func(*args,**kargs)
        return rateLimitedFunction
    wrapper.minInterval = interval
    return wrapper

@RateLimited(1)    #Function can be run 60 times per minute (Every Second)
def Print1():
    print("Print Every Second")

@RateLimited(10)     #Function can be run 6 times per minute (Every 10 Seconds)
def Print2():
    print("Print Every 10 Seconds")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        Print1()
        Print2()
```

This requires a new function for each print statement which must be defined outwith the loop.  If possible I would rather use something in one single line similar to the following syntax:

```
rateLimit("Print Every Second", 1, id=1)
rateLimit("Print Every 10 Seconds", 10, id=2)
```

Comment: Makes no sense - how distinguishes _rateLimit_ between different prints that way? You could use something like `def rateLimit(what, time_in_seconds, id):` and inside the function depending on the provided `id` decide if you print or not - store the last print time in a dict similar to above with id as key

Comment: I would push each log message onto a stack, and have a separate thread/process that prints the stack contents at an appropriate interval (ideally triggered by some kind of timer event).

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thank you for your comment, I have changed the requested syntax to use an ID.  I only meant for it to clarify that I am looking to use a single function to process all print statements.  I will try and create a proof of concept using a dict.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps take a look at the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html). You can set up a print queue and continue processing something else.

A *rough* example:

```
import threading 
import time 
from collections import deque 

class Printq:
  def __init__(self, initial=[], t=2):
    self.q=deque(initial)
    self.t=t
    threading.Timer(self.t, self.pq).start()
    
  def pq(self):
    if self.q:
      print(self.q.popleft())
    
    if self.q:
      threading.Timer(self.t, self.pq).start()
      
  def add(self, item):
    self.q.append(item)
    
q=Printq(list('123'))

while q.q:
  print("processing")
  time.sleep(1)
```

Prints:

```
processing
processing
1
processing
processing
2
processing
processing
processing
3
```

You can have multiple Printq's with different times concurrently:

```
q1=Printq(list('1234'))
q2=Printq([e*100 for e in range(1,6)],1)

while q1.q or q2.q:
  print("processing")
  time.sleep(1)
```

Prints:

```
processing
processing
100
1
processing
200
processing
300
2
processing
400
processing
500
3
processing
processing
4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach based on my comment. It sets up a `Logger` class which will print the contents of a `set` (for uniqueness) every N seconds. the `log` method appends to the message stack:

```
from threading import Timer
import time

class Logger():
    def __init__(self, timeout=3):
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.msgs = set()
        self._timer = None
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        self._timer = Timer(self.timeout, self.run)
        self._timer.start()

    def run(self):
        self.start()
        print(self.msgs)
        self.msgs = set()
        # Restart timer

    def log(self, msg):
        self.msgs.add(msg)

    def stop(self):
        self._timer.cancel()


# start the log timer function
logger = Logger()

# Log something every second
for i in range(12):
  # Log a recurring message
  logger.log("msg")
  # Log a unique message
  logger.log(i)
  time.sleep(1)

logger.stop()
```

output

```
{'msg', 0, 1, 2}
{'msg', 3, 4, 5}
{'msg', 6, 7, 8}
{'msg', 9, 10, 11}
```

Answer (score 0):

To meet your initial demand, I would try to build a *tagged* logger:

- each message would be associated with a tag
- each tag would have a *silence* timeout preventing it to actually log the message during a delay after a successful log

I would implemented it with a *config* dictionnary mapping each tag name to a delay in seconds and a current dictionnary recording for each tag what is the time for the next allowed message.

Code could be:

```
import time

class LimitedLogger:
    def __init__(self, /, **kwargs):
        for delta in kwargs.values():
            if delta < 0:
                raise ValueError("Tag values must be positive")
        self.conf = dict(kwargs.items())
        self.curr = dict()
        
    def log(self, tag, msg):
        if tag not in self.conf:
            raise ValueError(f'Tag {tag} is unknown')
        t = time.time()
        if tag not in self.curr:
            self._do_log(tag, msg, t)
        else:
            min_t = self.curr[tag]
            if t >= min_t:
                # actually print or log
                self._do_log(tag, msg, t)
    def _do_log(self, tag, msg, t):
        print(msg)
        self.curr[tag] = t + self.conf[tag]

    # optionaly removed passed timeouts from curr
    def clean(self):
        t = time.time()
        self.curr = {k: v for k, v in self.curr if v > t}

    # optionaly allow calls like log.err(msg)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name not in self.conf:
            raise AttributeError(f'{LimitedLogger} has no attribute {name}')
        return lambda msg: self.log(name, msg)
```

Usage example:

```
lg = LimitedLogger(warn=10, err=5)
while True:
    lg.err('Err')
    lg.warn('Warn')

    
Err        <-- immediate
Warn
Err        <-- after 5 seconds
Err        <-- after 10 seconds
Warn
Err        <-- after 15 seconds
...
```